# Performance issue when try to make rounded UIImage (using mask)

Tags: objective-c, c, ios7, core-animation

I've developed method which make from rect UIImage to rounded. The problem is that it decrease performance if do that operation for 10 different images in a row. Images have resolution 120x120

```
- (UIImage *)roundedImage:(UIImage*)anOriginalImage radius:(CGFloat)aRadius
{
    UIImage *result = nil;

    if (anOriginalImage != nil) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(anOriginalImage.size, NO, 0);
        [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, anOriginalImage.size}
                                    cornerRadius:aRadius] addClip];
        [anOriginalImage drawInRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, anOriginalImage.size}];
        result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    return result;
}
```

How to fix that?

Comment: you should try to make UIImageView round. with imageView.radius . not the UIImage.

Comment: @pawan UIImageView does not have a *radius* property. Do you mean set the *cornerRadius* property on the UIImageView's layer, like `imaageView.layer.cornerRadius = radius;`?

Comment: yes , sorry my mistake. it should be imaageView.layer.cornerRadius not imageView.radius; correct one is in my answer below. thanks matt

Answer (score 1):

Import the QuartzCore framework to get access to the .cornerRadius property of your UIView or UIImageView.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Also manually add it to your project's Frameworks folder.

Add this method to your view controller or wherever you need it:

```
-(void)setRoundedView:(UIImageView *)roundedView toDiameter:(float)newSize;
{
CGPoint saveCenter = roundedView.center;
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(roundedView.frame.origin.x, roundedView.frame.origin.y, newSize, newSize);
roundedView.frame = newFrame;
roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = newSize / 2.0;
roundedView.center = saveCenter;
}
```

To use it, just pass it a UIImageView and a diameter. This example assumes you have a UIImageView named "circ" added as a subview to your view. It should have a backgroundColor set so you can see it.

```
[self setRoundedView:circ toDiameter:100.0];
```

This just handles UIImageViews but you can generalize it to any UIView.

Comment: I don't use any UIView or UIImageView. I need UIImage only.

Comment: tell me how a data(byte) can be round & circle ? got my point